# How do I export saga and combine?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to separate sagas into multiple files.

In `analytics.js`:

```
const logEvent = function* logEvent() {

  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(action_type.LOG_EVENT)

    let params = {
      ...action.payload.eventParams,
    }

    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(
      action.payload.eventName,
      params
    )

  }
}


export const analyticsSagas = [
  logEvent
]
```

I'm trying to use it like from another file `index.js`:

```
import { analyticsSagas } from 'analytics'

const rootSaga = function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    analyticsSagas,
  ])
}
```

But it doesn't seem that sagas are being run with the approapriate actions.

Comment: I don't this the `all` effect works with multidim array. Try `yield all([...analyticsSagas])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Export your saga function from analytics.js like this:

```
export function* logEvent() { 
  // your code here 
}
```

Then in your index.js, you can just import it and then invoke the saga using yield*.

```
import { logEvent } from 'filePath/analytics.js';
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield* logEvent();
}
```